# Amplify- upgrade amplify to latest make Amplify.Auth?.currentUser?.userId

Tags: android, kotlin, aws-amplify

I have a sleeping tracker app written in Kotlin and its backend is Amplify but I got a lot of issues with syncing to the cloud, I got advice to upgrade the lib to the latest but my old implementation I was collecting userId from the sync method`Amplify.Auth?.currentUser?.userId` and this method called in many places all of them are sync after the new upgrade I have getCurrentUser as an async method

```
fun getUserId(callback: (String?) -> Unit) {
        Amplify.Auth.getCurrentUser({ authUser ->
            callback(authUser.userId)
        }, { exception ->
            Log.e("MyAmplifyApp", "Error getting the current user", exception)
            callback(null)
        })
    }
```

can I get the userId after the login and stored it in sharedperfernce and retrieve it when needed or that will break the old implementation

```
 val pid = "${period.getPeriodID()}- UserID:${AWS.uid}"


val uid by lazy {
        Amplify.Auth?.currentUser?.userId
    }
```

my save method

```
fun save(model: Model, onComplete:(res:Response) -> Unit){
        Amplify.DataStore.save(model,
            {
                onComplete(Response(true,it.item(),null))
            },
            {
                it.localizedMessage?.let { it1 -> onComplete(Response(false,null,it1)) }
                amplifyRetry()
            }
        )

    }
```

this app runs in the background for days and that means I need to make sure the access token are refreshed automatically and the data will be stored in the cloud when I called `Amplify.DataStore.save`